# Calling an id from another XML layout on android using LayoutInflater not working

Tags: android

Well in my case i have 2 XML Layouts so far,activity_main.xml and reserve.xml.
I want to call the ImageButton id from reserve.xml to be executed from the MainActivity that uses my activity_main.xml layout.

I am trying to change layouts on a click from the action bar like activity_main.xml to reserve.xml and vice versa. Because i don't want to use intents. So i'm setting the view on onOptionsItemSelected function.

So because of this i tried to use LayoutInflater And View to call the id,but its giving me a nullPointerException error.

/*THIS IS WHERE I SET THE VIEW OR CHANGE MY LAYOUTS*/

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.home:
             //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                inflater =(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
                this.setContentView(view);
            return true;

            case R.id.reserve:
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reservation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //setContentView(R.layout.reserve);
                inflater =(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reserve, null);
                this.setContentView(view);
            return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

/*THIS IS WHERE I CALL THE ID AND THE HIGHLIGHTED LINE GIVES ME THE ERROR*/

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar(); // or MainActivity.getInstance().getActionBar()
    //bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x000));
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);  // required to force redraw, without, gray color
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);


        date = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        datepicker = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /** Listener for click event of the button */
        datepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
              //showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        /** Get the current date */
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        pMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        pDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        /** Display the current date in the TextView */
        updateDisplay();

}
```

I just want to ask if is there any possible way i can do this if this is my idea of changing pages on my app?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

you have to call findViewById on the view which have been inflated for example

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reverse, null);
TextView one = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.WHATEVER);
```

Comment: Yep i already did that..this is my code on that.
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reserve, null);
   
    date = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
         datepicker = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

Comment: copy & paste your code and mention the line which exception is thrown

Comment: please update your question with all necessary lines of your code

Comment: oh okay,sorry im just new here :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can swipe Activities like that. Why not use Intent and save yourself from all that trouble or use Tabs instead.

Comment: yeah i guess so,im just trying to find an alternative way of changing activities like what facebook has.. :)

Comment: facebook app uses Tab Layout you should check that out ;).